# pause in javascript doesn't work in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

This is the sleep function:

```
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a function for actualize the textarea content:

```
    Luminosidad.prototype.prueba = function(num)
{
    document.getElementById("pruebas").value = num; 
}
```

When i want do it in a loop, i can only see the last value.
This is the code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        sleep(this.opcion.velocidad);
        this.prueba(i);
    }
```

On the textarea, i can only see "7", the last number. It is like don't actualize correcly. Why can it happens? (sleep works correctly)

Comment: Give a try to `setTimeout()`

Comment: Javascript is single threaded so for efficiency user agents don't update the display until functions terminate. Make all the changes you want within a function, you'll only see the finished product.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can it happens?

Because you never give the browser a chance to show the updates you're making, because you're keeping the UI thread busy looping pointlessly.

Busy-waits are essentially never the right answer to basically any situation.

In this case, what you're looking for is either `setInterval` of a series of `setTimeout`s:

```js
function Luminosidad() {}
Luminosidad.prototype.prueba = function(num) {
  document.getElementById("pruebas").value = num;
};
Luminosidad.prototype.loop = function(milliseconds) {
  var i = 1;
  var obj = this;

  setTimeout(next, milliseconds);

  function next() {
    obj.prueba(i++);
    if (i < 8) {
      setTimeout(next, milliseconds);
    }
  }
};
var l = new Luminosidad();
l.loop(500);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pruebas">
```

**Note:** The `loop` function returns **before** any updates to the `pruebas` element. If you have logic that needs to run after all the updates are complete, you'll want to have `loop` either accept a callback or return a promise.

Since JavaScript doesn't have a standard form of promise yet (they're coming in ES6, so not far away at all), here's an example of having a callback:

```js
// Requires that your browser support ES6 promises!
function Luminosidad() {}
Luminosidad.prototype.prueba = function(num) {
  document.getElementById("pruebas").value = num;
};
Luminosidad.prototype.loop = function(milliseconds, callback) {
  var i = 1;
  var obj = this;

  setTimeout(next, milliseconds);

  function next() {
    obj.prueba(i++);
    if (i < 8) {
      setTimeout(next, milliseconds);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
};
var l = new Luminosidad();
l.loop(500, function() {
  // This runs when everything is done
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "All done"
  );
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pruebas">
```

In ES6, you might use a promise instead:

```js
// Requires that your browser support ES6 promises!
function Luminosidad() {}
Luminosidad.prototype.prueba = function(num) {
  document.getElementById("pruebas").value = num;
};
Luminosidad.prototype.loop = function(milliseconds) {
  var obj = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var i = 1;

    setTimeout(next, milliseconds);

    function next() {
      obj.prueba(i++);
      if (i < 8) {
        setTimeout(next, milliseconds);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }
  });
};
var l = new Luminosidad();
l.loop(500).then(function() {
  // This runs when everything is done
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "All done"
  );
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pruebas">
```